# Variable scope in VBScript functions

Tags: vbscript, scope

I have a question about variable scope in VBScript.  I know there's the following keywords (from [autoitscript.com](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Dim.htm)):

1. Dim = Local scope if the variable name doesn't already exist globally (in which case it reuses the global variable!)
2. Global = Forces creation of the variable in the Global scope
3. Local = Forces creation of the variable in the Local/Function scope

Imagine that I have the following .vbs file:

```
Dim strPath

strPath = "C:\folder"

DisplayPath strPath

Sub DisplayPath(strPath) 'Does this strPath get it's own local scope?
  MsgBox strPath
End Sub
```

**In the function: `DisplayPath(strPath)`, is `strPath` a *local* variable?  Or do functions/subs have access to the `strPath` defined at the top of the main section of the script as a *global* variable?**

Also, what's the point of explicitly using `Dim` versus just defining variables as I use them, which is possible in scripting languages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `strPath` in the `DisplayPath` procedure will be a new variable but not for the reasons you expect, there is subtle problem with your code that will cloud the issue.

When calling `Sub` procedure the VBScript syntax does not include parentheses.  For example:-

```
Sub MyProc(Param1, Param2)
  '' # Do stuff
End Sub

MyProc("Hello", "World")
```

the above would result in a syntax error.  It should be called:-

```
MyProc "Hello", "World"
```

Now when there is only one parameter a syntax error does not occur.  This is because another use of parentheses is as part of an expression e.g. '(a + b) * c'.  In the case of:-

```
DisplayPath(strPath)
```

VBScript resolves the "expression"  `(strPath)` and pass the **result** to `DisplayPath`.  Its this **result** that gives rise to new storage hold the result the expression.

Had you called with

```
DisplayPath strPath
```

no new created.

However what about this:-

```
Sub DisplayPath(something)
  MsgBox something
End Sub
```

There is still no new storage allocated.  `something` will point at the same memory that `strPath` does.

**Edit**

The code below works:-

```
Dim strPath

strPath = "c:\folder"

Display


Sub Display()
  MsgBox strPath
End Sub
```

The declaration of `strPath` outside of a procedure causes it to have global scope.

As to the point of using explicit `Dim` what would happen if the assignment line above looked like this?

```
 strPath = "c:\folder"
```

A new variable called `strPath` would come into existence and `strPath` would remain empty.  You should **always** begin your VBScript files with the line:-

```
Option Explicit
```

This will force you to explicitly `Dim` all variables to be used and will save you hours of debugging time.

Comment: very helpful, +1, thanks.  I'm glad you cleared up that distinction between passing by reference and passing by value (and creating new storage).  However, what I also want to know is if `strPath` is global and accessible by all the functions/subs in the script, even if I don't pass them in as local function variables.

Comment: Very important observation, saved me some time today!!

Comment: Simple syntax errors regarding parentheses I easily solved by using `Call MyProc("Hello", "World")`.