# Scope of a variable in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, scope

Consider the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Count : Count = 4


'Case-I
Sub Display1()

 MsgBox(Count)

End Sub

'Case-II

Sub Display2(Count)

 MsgBox(Count)

End Sub
```

***Confusion***

- here should the variable `Count` will be accessible to the both
  `method` or only to the `Display2` method?
- If the variable `count` is not accessible with `Display1` method,then
  is there any way to make it useable within any sub or function
  without passing it to that `Sub` or `Function`
- Now if I updated the `Count`variable from the `Display2` sub will
  that value can be used to other `function` or `sub` provided that
  VBScript has `global` variable declarations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable scope in VBScript functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835195/variable-scope-in-vbscript-functions)

Comment: Have you run the above code? What are `functions` for? That can be your next question..

Comment: The reference for *VBScript* variables starts here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: @Cygwinnian - please delete your comment, because it links to docs for Visual Basic, not VBScript.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner So variables decalred with `dim` are falling under `global` or `local` scope?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thanks for checking. I accidentally though he was referring to visual basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `count` is declared outside of any function or sub-procedure, hence its scope is global here. Global variable can be used in any function or sub-procedure and its value can be change in anywhere in program flow.

Now if you make call to this procedure and run the .vbs file, message box will display `4` in both cases.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Count : Count = 4
'Case-I
Sub Display1()
 MsgBox(Count)
End Sub

'Case-II
Sub Display2(Count)
 MsgBox(Count)
End Sub

Call Display1()
Call Display2(Count)
```

If you change value of `count` variable in any function or sub procedure, its value will change for other procedure also as its scope is global.

Option Explicit

```
Dim Count : Count = 4
'Case-I
Sub Display1()
 Count = 5               ''value changed here 
 MsgBox(Count)
End Sub

'Case-II
Sub Display2(Count)
 MsgBox(Count)
End Sub

Call Display1()
Call Display2(Count)
```

In above case, both message box will display `5`